# How to get a feature requirement tag in the documentation generated by `cargo doc`?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

If you look at the [Tokio docs on docs.rs](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.18/tokio/process/index.html) there's a blue tag indicating that a feature must be activated in order to access this API:

[image]

I would like to enable this for my crate as well, how can this be done?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The bad news is: It's a nightly-only feature for now.

The good news is: docs.rs uses nightly by default.

---

To get this to work all you need is to enable the [`doc_cfg` feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/doc-cfg.html) and apply `#doc(cfg)` to the item being documented

```
#![feature(doc_cfg)]

#[doc(cfg(feature = "macros"))]
pub fn test() {}
```

---

Because this is a nightly-only feature, you probably don't want to enable it all the time. `tokio` defines the following in its `Cargo.toml` to only enable this feature on docs.rs:

```
# docs.rs-specific configuration
[package.metadata.docs.rs]
# document all features
all-features = true
# defines the configuration attribute `docsrs`
rustdoc-args = ["--cfg", "docsrs"]
```

and then they use

```rust
// only enables the `doc_cfg` feature when
// the `docsrs` configuration attribute is defined
#![cfg_attr(docsrs, feature(doc_cfg))]

#[cfg_attr(docsrs, doc(cfg(feature = "macros")))]
pub fn test() {}
```

Comment: To test locally, use: `RUSTDOCFLAGS="--cfg docsrs" cargo +nightly doc --all-features`

Answer (score 11):

In the latest nightly (since v1.57 maybe), you can use feature `doc_auto_cfg` (merged in [PR#90502](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/90502)) and you no longer need to manually mark features for `doc`, just write `cfg` as before:

```rust
#![feature(doc_auto_cfg)]

#[cfg(feature = "macros")]
pub fn test() {}
```

To check it locally, run `cargo +nightly doc --all-features`.

If you want to continue using stable for commands other than `cargo doc`, you can:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(doc, feature(doc_auto_cfg))]

#[cfg(feature = "macros")]
pub fn test() {}
```

---

**UPDATE**: The above method still requires `doc-tests` to run nightly, and it also requires dependents' `doc` command to run nightly. A workaround is that we can enable the `doc_auto_cfg` feature only under nightly.

In `Cargo.toml`, adding:

```
[build-dependencies]
rustc_version = "0.4.0"
```

Create a `build.rs` file with the following contents:

```rust
use rustc_version::{version_meta, Channel};

fn main() {
    // Set cfg flags depending on release channel
    let channel = match version_meta().unwrap().channel {
        Channel::Stable => "CHANNEL_STABLE",
        Channel::Beta => "CHANNEL_BETA",
        Channel::Nightly => "CHANNEL_NIGHTLY",
        Channel::Dev => "CHANNEL_DEV",
    };
    println!("cargo:rustc-cfg={}", channel)
}
```

Then we can enable the feature `doc_auto_cfg` this way:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(all(doc, CHANNEL_NIGHTLY), feature(doc_auto_cfg))]
```

Since `docs.rs` uses nightly by default, the documentation on there will be shown as you expected.

Comment: this fails for doc-tests on stable as, I guess, the `doc` feature is enabled.  I also tried `#![cfg_attr(all(doc, not(test)), feature(doc_auto_cfg))]` and `#![cfg_attr(all(doc, not(doctest)), feature(doc_auto_cfg))]` without success

Comment: @FujiApple I have updated the answer, please check if it works for you :)

Comment: Does this require setting this in Cargo.toml to get crates.io to show docs for all features?

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
all-features = true

Comment: @extremeandy I think yes. Rustc won't see a module if it is disabled by `cfg`.